# Querying multiple ElasticSearch indexes with different structures both nested and 'plain'

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

Is it possible to query in ElasticSearch on multiple indexes with different structures where some  indexes have nested structures?

For instance when I have 2 indexes for products and documents:

```
PUT /my_products
{
  "mappings" : {
    "Product" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : { "type" : "long" },
        "title" : {"type" : "keyword"},
        "description" : {"type": "text"}
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /my_documents
{
  "mappings" : {
    "Documentation" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : { "type" : "long" },
        "title" : {"type" : "keyword"},
        "description" : {"type": "text"},
        "fileInfo" : { 
          "type": "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {"type" : "long"},
            "filename" : {"type" : "keywords"},
            "content" : {"type" : "text"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then my query looks like:

```
GET /my_*/_search
{ 
  "query" : {
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {"query_string":{"query":"mysearchstring"}},
        {"nested": {
           "path": "fileInfo",
              "query": {"query_string": {
                           "fields": [
                               "fileInfo.content"
                           ],
                           "query": "mysearchstring"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
         ]
      }
    },
    "size":10
}
```

However this gives me an error message on the my_products index:

`"reason" : "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [file]"`

Is there another way to query both indexes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_index field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) when you are querying across multiple indexes.
Modify your search query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "my_products"
                }
              },
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "mysearchstring"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "my_documents"
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "fileInfo",
                  "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "fields": [
                        "fileInfo.content"
                      ],
                      "query": "mysearchstring"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but somehow your solution still throws me the same error. I'm using ES6.8 and the _index is also in the documentation of that. I found a solution in using the `"ignore_unmapped" : true ` option on the nested query.

Answer (score 0):

I got his to work using the `"ignore_unmapped"` option. My Query now looks like:

```
{ 
  "query" : {
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {"query_string":{"query":"mysearchstring"}},
        {"nested": {
           "path": "fileInfo",
           "ignore_unmapped" : true,
           "query": {"query_string": {
                           "fields": [
                               "fileInfo.content"
                           ],
                           "query": "mysearchstring"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
         ]
      }
    },
    "size":10
}
```